# Overloading istream >> operator for a base class using

Tags: c++, class, oop

So I have a base class `Members` which has 1 class inheriting from it, which is `Admin`. On the `Members` class, I have 2 chars : `username` and `password`.  On the `Admin` I have 2 others, `city` and `job`.

The problem appears when using istream. For the `Members` class, I have istream for `username` and `password`. For the `Admin` class, I used an istream with `in>>(Members)a;` included (to get the istream from `Members` class . When I access it in the main function, I introduce the `username` and the `password` for the new `Admin` , but then it calls the default constructor from `Members` Class.

What should I put to get my `username` and `password` that I introduced and not the default ones ?

Members overload

[image]

Admins overload

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about what you should put in your code, but I can tell you what's missing in this *question*: your *code*. You'd be amazed how effectively your *code* "speaks" to a wide range of readers, thereby eliminating nearly all of this paragraph and rooting only the fundamental question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please ask a clear question giving part of code that matters you.

Comment: Hello again. Sorry for the bad post, it's my first one. I have added two photos with my istream functions in each classes.

Comment: The problem is : I introduce username and password from keyboard for admin, and when it is calling it, it's calling the default constructors ones not the ones I introduced

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Pos the text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Introduce two new virtual member functions, `void Members::readVars(istream&)` and `void Admin::readVars(istream&)`. The second calls the first.

Then you define only one operator, `istream& operator >> (istream&, Members&)`, which  calls `readVars(istream&)`.